# TypeError: set_actuation_vector(): incompatible function arguments ; Pydrake

Tags: drake

Used AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph, import lines shown below, when running, passes assertion checks but gets error :

```
TypeError: set_actuation_vector(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: pydrake.multibody.tree.JointActuator, u_instance: numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1]], u: Optional[numpy.ndarray[numpy.float64[m, 1], flags.writeable]]) -> None

Invoked with: <JointActuator name='joint_RW_J_Pitch' index=0 model_instance=2>, array([0.])
```

```
from pydrake.all import (
    AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph,
    Simulator,
    StartMeshcat,
    DiagramBuilder,
)
from pydrake.multibody.tree import JointIndex, JointActuatorIndex, JointActuator

    plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, time_step=0.0)
    parser.package_map().Add("URDF_LargeWings", os.path.join(project_dir))
    parser.AddModelFromFile(os.path.join(project_dir, "urdf", "URDF_LargeWings.sdf"))
    plant.Finalize()

    rw_passive = plant.GetJointActuatorByName("joint_RW_J_Pitch")
    lw_passive = plant.GetJointActuatorByName("joint_LW_J_Pitch")
    assert isinstance(rw_passive, JointActuator)
    assert rw_passive.joint().num_velocities() == 1
    u_inst = np.array([[0.0]])
    rw_passive.set_actuation_vector(u_inst)
```

The joint itself is defined in the sdf as a revolute joint so the assertion matches up. Actuation vector should be 1x1.
I've tried with different arrays like np.array([[0.0]]).
Checked the types too, `u_inst.dtype` is `float64`, array shape is `(1,1)`.

Let me know if more information or source files are needed, my SDF also includes meshfiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [JointActuator.set_actuation_vector](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.tree.html?highlight=set_actuation_vector#pydrake.multibody.tree.JointActuator.set_actuation_vector) has two arguments, `u_instance` and `u`.  The type signature is a little bit misleading -- it marks `u` as `Optional[]` but the details say `RuntimeError if u is nullptr` so its not actually optional.  In short, the problem with the code is that its only passing 1 argument instead of 2.